# How to specify that a pdf is returned in swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have a get call in my swagger REST API that needs to return a pdf file. There is no clear example / documentation on how to do this without causing a syntax error.

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: Returns PDF
      schema: [application/pdf]
```

and

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: Returns PDF
      schema: 
        type: file
```

and

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: Returns PDF
      schema:
        type:  [application/pdf]
```

all fail. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: Returns PDF
      schema: 
        type: file
```

Out of the options you gave, that's the right option. Also, make sure to use `produces: [application/pdf]`

If it fails for you, make sure you use the latest version of the editor. There was a bug related to the `file` type that was recently resolved.

Comment: With Open API 3.0 , try below

`responses:
        '200':
          description: A PDF file
          content:
            application/pdf:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary`


Documentation: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/
Section:Response That Returns a File

Comment: @dev1918 you should post it as another answer.

Answer (score 23):

With Open API 3.0 ,try below responses:

```
get:
  summary: Returns the report in the PDF format
  responses:
    '200':
      description: A PDF file
      content:
        application/pdf:
          schema:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

Documentation: swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses

Section: Response That Returns a File